# Exchange Server Cannot Receive External Email From Postfix Relay

Tags: linux, windows, postfix, exchange, smtp

Server A = Exchange Server (mail.example.com)
Server B = SMTP Server on VPS (smtp.example.com)
I use 2 **separate servers** to build my Mail Server because of my ISP **block Server A port 25**
So the configuration is **Server B(Postfix)** as my **Relay SMTP**
Then **Server A** connected to **Server B** through **Smarthost**
Now i already can **Sending Email to External Email** by changing **Smarthost Port to 587**

```
Set-SendConnector -identity "smart host connector" -Port:587
```

The Problem is i can't receive email from External Email, when i check my **Server B logs**, the **status=bounced**

```
Dec 22 20:09:30 postfix postfix/qmgr[4160]: AF6A72044F: from=<user@gmail.com>, size=2550, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 22 20:09:30 postfix postfix/local[4167]: AF6A72044F: to=<user@example.com>, relay=local, delay=0.46, delays=0.45/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "user")
```

There is my configuration on **Server B**

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_un$
myhostname = smtp.example.com
#ADDED LINE
mydomain = example.com
myorigin = $mydomain

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = [mail.example.com]:587, mail.example.com, example.com
local_recipient_maps =

relayhost =
mynetworks = 38.123.399.10
relay_domains = mail.example.com

mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

Im so confused about this, i can sending email to outside normally, but can't receive from outside
Is there something wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the relay server IP to the receive connector in exchange server? If not, follow these guidance：[Receive connectors](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/mail-flow/connectors/receive-connectors?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=exchserver-2019) and [How to Configure a Relay Connector for Exchange Server 2010](https://practical365.com/exchange-server/how-to-configure-a-relay-connector-for-exchange-server-2010/)

In addition, a similar [thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/129ee10d-e5c5-40e0-9646-a2724af01647/postfix-as-relay-to-exchange?forum=exchangesvr3rdpartyappslegacy) for your reference as well.

Sorry for that I'm not familiar with Postfix, but i have done some research, here are some solutions in the blog for your reference: [Postfix mail for domain.com loops back to myself Error and Solution](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/postfix-mail-for-domaincom-loops-back-to-myself-error-and-solution/)

Comment: the problem is fixed now by using Postfix Transport for delivered via relay host, thankyou...